# TypeScript var vs import

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, what is the difference between

```
 import http = require('http');
```

and

```
 var http = require('http');
```

I am seeing both ways being used in code source, are they interchangeable?

Comment: The first one looks invalid to me ?

Comment: Do you mean `import http from 'http'` maybe? The former is a ES6 module import declaration, the latter is a CommonJS module import.

Comment: @adeneo, the first one is what gets auto generated by visual studio using their Typescript + node.js addin

Comment: Okay, but that's still not javascript but probably Typescript. In javascript it's like Felix wrote above, either the ES6 `import stuff from module` or the commonJS version used in Node with a regular variable and a call to `require()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `import` statement is TypeScript and will not run as-is in Node. You will need to compile (transpile?) it to JavaScript first. You can read the TypeScript docs for more info about how the TypeScript `import` keyword works. See the ["Using Modules" subsection of the "Namespaces and Modules" section of the TypeScript handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#using-modules).

There is an `import` keyword in JavaScript too, but it doesn't work the way TypeScript's `import` works. It will only work in versions of Node that support ES6 modules. There are differences between this `import` and `require` that you can read about at ["ES6 Modules: The Final Syntax"](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html). That `import` is something you can compare/contrast with `require` but not really `var`.

Comment: how does this answer the question ? the information is interesting but it is not an answer.

Comment: @viscanner The question was edited subsequently to add "TypeScript" (which wasn't in the original question). Then  **8 months after this answer was posted**, it was edited again to remove "Node.js" making this answer **appear** invalid. This answer addressed the question as it appeared at the time this answer was written.

Comment: @Trott, MS has removed the link you provided named "Going External". I paged through their new github docs and couldn't find the page. Any chance you can find it and put a quick jist about it in your answer rather than a link?

Comment: @bgura A lot has changed with both TypeScript and Node.js but the relevant section has been renamed "Using Modules" and can be found at http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#using-modules. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same inquiry. Just found this in the "Alias" section of Typescript:

> This is similar to using var, but also works on the type and namespace meanings of the imported symbol. Importantly, for values, import is a distinct reference from the original symbol, **so changes to an aliased var will not be reflected in the original variable**

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#aliases

Comment: That's the main difference. if we use var it seems that it passes by reference. In English this means (from my understanding, correct me if I'm wrong) that any changes that happen to the object you assigned to var, will change even if you didn't reassigned it. Whereas using import will create an independent copy of it.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript `import` keyword has several usages, some depending on the environment, explaining why it's confusing. Let's see that with the minimum detail level (cause in real project it can be even more complex):

### Modules CommonJs / Node

> @mfc: This is the case that corresponds to your question.

The TypeScript project is using CommonJs modules, typically a node project:

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        ...
    }
}
```

In this context, `import _ = require('http');` (*version #1*) is transpiled to `var _ = require('http');` (*version #2*). So version #1 is the TypeScript syntax whereas version #2 is the JavaScript syntax.

`require()` is supported in version 1 but not in version #2 (error `[ts] Cannot find name 'require'.`) unless adding node typings to the project via `npm i @types/node --save-dev` *(see this [stackoverflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/#35961176))*.

### Modules ES6

> @mfc: This is not the case you've asked for. But it's in [Trott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859748/#29859774) so I've taken it into account.

`import` is the ES6 keyword and has its [own syntax](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html):

- "Full" import of named exports: `import * as lib from 'lib';`
- "Picking" import of named exports: `import { square, diag } from 'lib';`
- Import of the default export: `import myFunc from 'myFunc';`

These imports are transpiled differently according to the module compiler option mentioned above:

- `ES6` → no change
- `CommonJS` → `var ... = require('...');`
- `AMD` → `define(...);`

### Namespaces

#### Alias

> @mfc: This is not the case you've asked for. But it's in [Jose A's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859748/#36001649) so I've added here to have the full picture.

In a [`namespace`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html), formerly called "(internal) module", `import` is used to create an [alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#aliases), a shortcut to an exported element of another namespace.

```js
namespace Root.Branch.Leaf {
    export const configPath = '...';
}

namespace LeafClient {
    import configPath = Root.Branch.Leaf.configPath;
    console.log(`configPath=${configPath}`);
}
```

The line `import configPath = Root.Branch.Leaf.configPath;` is transpiled into `var configPath = Root.Branch.Leaf.configPath;`, cf. [TypeScript PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20Root.Branch.Leaf%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20const%20configPath%20%3D%20'...'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20LeafClient%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20import%20configPath%20%3D%20Root.Branch.Leaf.configPath%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%60configPath%3D%24%7BconfigPath%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%7D).

Watch out for usages outside a namespace, since it created global variables!

#### Global module

Some libraries modify the global object *(the `window` global variable in a browser)*, for instance:

- jQuery and its `$` global variable,
- [reflect-metadata](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata) to extends [`Reflect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect).

ES6 syntax also allows to load this kind of library using a [side effects only import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only): `import "reflect-metadata";`

TypeScript supports this [kind of imports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-module-for-side-effects-only). The compiler will try to fetch the corresponding [typing definition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#-reference-ing-a-module) to understand the library effects, for instance the new method [`Reflect.getMetadata()`](https://rbuckton.github.io/reflect-metadata/#syntax).