# TypeScript getting error TS2304: cannot find name ' require'

Tags: node.js, typescript, definitelytyped

I am trying to get my first TypeScript and DefinitelyTyped Node.js application up and running, and running into some errors.

I am getting the error "TS2304: Cannot find name 'require' " when I attempt to transpile a simple TypeScript Node.js page. I have read through several other occurrences of this error on Stack Overflow, and I do not think I have similar issues.
I am running at the shell prompt the command:

```
tsc movie.server.model.ts.
```

The contents of this file are:

```
'use strict';

/// <reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts" />

/*    movie.server.model.ts - definition of movie schema */

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var foo = 'test';
```

The error is thrown on the `var mongoose=require('mongoose')` line.

The contents of the typings/tsd.d.ts file are:

```
/// <reference path="node/node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="requirejs/require.d.ts" />
```

The .d.ts file references were placed in the appropriate folders and added to typings/tsd.d.ts by the commands:

```
tsd install node --save
tsd install require --save
```

The produced .js file seems to work fine, so I could ignore the error. But I would appreciate knowing why this error occurs and what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `when I attempt to transpile a simple ts node page` < how are you transpiling ... which utility

Comment: I am just running on the command line by typing the command: tsc movie.server.model.ts.   FWIW this is on a Mac.

Comment: The same issue also occurred in the IDE I was using Visual Studio Code.  I will try it my other IDE, IntelliJ.  I assumed that dropping to the command line was the cleanest way to test this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43129815/2106820

Comment: How about `import  { mongoose } from 'mongoose'`?

Comment: If you tried the accepted answer and did not work, check this other one https://stackoverflow.com/a/57946781/1461862

Answer (score 953, accepted):

### Quick and Dirty

If you just have one file using require, or you're doing this for demo purposes you can define require at the top of your TypeScript file.

```
declare var require: any
```

### TypeScript 2.x

If you are using TypeScript 2.x you no longer need to have Typings or Definitely Typed installed. Simply install the following package.

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

[The Future of Declaration Files (6/15/2016)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)

> Tools like Typings and tsd will continue to work, and we’ll be working
> alongside those communities to ensure a smooth transition.

Verify or Edit your **src**/tsconfig.app.json so that it contains the following:

```
...
"types": [ "node" ],
"typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ]
...
```

Make sure is the file in the **src** folder and no the one on the root app folder.

By default, any package under @types is already included in your build **unless** you've specified either of these options.  [Read more](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)

### TypeScript 1.x

Using typings (DefinitelyTyped's replacement) you can specify a definition directly from a GitHub repository.

Install typings

```
npm install typings -g --save-dev
```

Install the requireJS type definition from DefinitelyType's repo

```
typings install dt~node --save --global
```

### Webpack

If you are using Webpack as your build tool you can include the Webpack types.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/webpack-env
```

Update your `tsconfig.json` with the following under `compilerOptions`:

```
"types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ]
```

This allows you to do `require.ensure` and other Webpack specific functions.

### Angular CLI

With CLI you can follow the Webpack step above and add the "types" block to your `tsconfig.app.json`.

Alternatively, you could use the preinstalled `node` types. Keep in mind this will include additional types to your client-side code that are not really available.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    // other options
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: why not just "typings install --save --ambient require"?

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I've updated the answer.  I didn't know require existed.

Comment: i get an error with this `Unable to find "require" ("npm") in the registry`. Is require part of a larger set of nodeJS typings?

Comment: typings v1.2.0 should be: typings install dt~require --save --global

Comment: i tihnk this is WRONG as its related to typings for requireJS, not node's built in `require`. maybe its right answer for some variation of ES5 output target but not the general case.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and this answer may help others who want to just get going with node. also if you're using atom typescript make sure to have         `"module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",` in your tsconfig. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37912109/1146785

Comment: @dcsan You're right. I've updated the answer to reflect using node.js instead of require.

Comment: this isn't working for me using TS2, it doesn't seem to be picking up the @types/node definitions somehow. any ideas why?

Comment: Could be something with your TypeScript config. Try deleting the tsconfig.json and recreating with `tsc --init` just to see if it works.  You can also try building the file manually (with tsc command) to see if its just the IDE thats not picking up the typings

Comment: Please refer to jordan awnser. In my case I had install the following @types so I added -> "types": ["node","es6-promise", "core-js", "jasmine"] <- to compilerOptions in tsconfig.json

Comment: @Lothre1 configuring those options is only necessary when you've specified typeRoots or types.  The default tsconfig will pick these up automatically.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

Comment: FINALLY got rid of the errors! I missed the step of adding the 'types' to the tsconfig. It look web storm a second to resolve everything. Thank you!!

Comment: Hmm followed all your steps, but it says no for me.

Comment: There's an error in your code. It's not `typeroots` but `typeRoots`  with a capital `R`

Comment: No problem sir ! :)

Comment: Works here too :)

Comment: For me the optional step wasn't so optional. Despite I wasn't using types before.

Comment: I still does not understand why I had to write "@types/node" as a dependency when Node.js is istalled globally on my PC? Any suggestions?

Comment: @Seagull `@types/node` are the TypeScript definitions. Node does not include these, nor should they.

Comment: This is it `npm install @types/node --save-dev` and a restart for dumb VsCode !

Comment: According to the documentation either types or typeRoots should be specified in the compiler options. Not both.

Comment: This answer, I tried like a fool and it caused my entire application, that at least was working, to blow up with 7 successive errors all saying the same thing... TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'. Hastily backing out... Core 2 .Net VueJs Typescript project... try at your own risk'

Comment: @Clarence sorry the answer didn't help?

Comment: Still getting this TS2304 error in TSC 2.9.2 even with this answers ideas.

Comment: Most likely you are editing the wrong `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: how about solution for TS version 3, cause above is not working for angular 7

Comment: in my case for TS version 3 and angular 7 I had to put typings.d.ts into src, cause on same level with src it is ignored silently.

Comment: Be warning there is 2 tsconfig one in src and one at the root

Comment: I had a similar issue, but the only things I needed to change were the target.

Comment: MAKE SURE THAT YOU --> Edit your src/tsconfig.app.json the one in SRC and not in the Root of the app folder.

Comment: TYVM, this helped me realize I forgot to update the tsconfig.app.json and the tsconfig.lib.json for my libraries and is why I was getting issues. Lead me down the path to correction!

Answer (score 138):

**For TypeScript 2.x**, there are now two steps:

1. Install a package that defines `require`. For example:

   ```
   npm install @types/node --save-dev
   ```
2. Tell TypeScript to include it globally in `tsconfig.json`:

   ```
   {
       "compilerOptions": {
           "types": ["node"]
       }
   }
   ```

The second step is only important if you need access to globally available functions such as `require`. For most packages, you should just use the `import package from 'package'` pattern. There's no need to include every package in the tsconfig.json types array above.

Comment: You can either use lib for some es5 https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#including-built-in-type-declarations-with---lib

Eq: "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es5",
            "es2015.promise",
            "es2015.collection"
        ]

Comment: After adding `"types": ["jasmine", "hammerjs"]` to `tsconfig.js` I hade to add `node` as well. Thanks Jordan.

Comment: When I follow this advice, it breaks all of my imports. For example, `import express from "express";` is now telling me that I need to try installing @types/express or add a .d.ts file for it.

Comment: If You have more `@types/...` than just `@types/node` folder don't add `"types": ["node"]` in `tsconfig.json` because TypeScript compiller will omit other not mentioned packages. This will break your IDEs types resolving. It is written here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

Comment: That solution works for me in an ionic project without problems, thank you :)

Comment: Would be nice if types/node was bundled in TypeScript

Answer (score 84):

You can

```
declare var require: any
```

Or, for more comprehensive support, use [DefinitelyTyped's require.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/requirejs/require.d.ts)

Also, instead of `var mongoose = require('mongoose')`, you could try the following

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose' // or
import mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

Comment: Just about using `use strict` in TypeScript:
[basarat answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610728/what-does-use-strict-add-for-typescript-code#answer-33619812) and [“Use Strict” needed in a TypeScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391760/use-strict-needed-in-a-typescript-file). It is necessary to use `use strict` in TypeScript.

Comment: Hm, according to that answer it's not necessary but might be beneficial to use `"use strict"`, I'll edit my answer

Comment: using declare var require isn't fixing the real problem; just hiding it.

Comment: @Ant right, keep in mind this is from 2015, and also, I'd argue there's no "problem" to fix. TypeScript 2.0 now solves this elegantly of course

Answer (score 48):

In my case, it was a super stupid problem, where the `src/tsconfig.app.json` was overriding the `tsconfig.json` setting.

So, I had this in `tsconfig.json`:

```
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
```

And this one in `src/tsconfig.app.json`:

```
    "types": []
```

I hope someone finds this helpful, as this error was causing me gray hairs.

Comment: This is the problem I faced. Thanks

Comment: We had the same issue. This comment helps to include the "node" in the correct file; in our case, we need to adjust the tsconfig.lib.json file because it was a submodule of the main project.

Answer (score 14):

*This answer relates to modern setups (TypeScript 2.x, [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) > 2.x)*

You *don't* need to install @types/node (which is all of Node.js types and is irrelevant for front-end code, actually complicating things such as setTimout different return values, etc..

You *do* need to install @types/webpack-env

`npm i -D @types/webpack-env`

which gives the runtime signatures that Webpack has (including `require`, `require.ensure`, etc.)

Also make sure that your tsconfig.json file has no set 'types' array -> which will make it pickup all type definitions in your node_modules/@types folder.

If you want to restrict search of types you can set the typeRoot property to node_modules/@types.

Comment: this is important remark **also make sure that your tsconfig.json has no set 'types' array -> which will make it pickup all type definitions in your node_modules/@types folder**

Comment: Are there any other steps needed with the webpack approach? I get a compile error ` error TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'.`

Answer (score 10):

Instead of:

```js
'use strict';

/// <reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts" />
```

Try:

```js
/// <reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts" />

'use strict';
```

i.e. reference path first.

Comment: Works, but kind of dirty IMO - it basically hides the error instead of correcting it. Perfect for demos and quick scripts, but not for production

Answer (score 10):

Just for reference, I am using *Angular 7.1.4*, *TypeScript 3.1.6*, and the only thing I need to do is to add this line in `tsconfig.json`:

```
    "types": ["node"], // within compilerOptions
```

Comment: did that. Still got this error: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig. - did npm install.

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution was to use the TSD command:

```
tsd install node --save
```

Which adds/updates the `typings/tsd.d.ts` file and that file contains all the type definitions that are required for a node application.

At the top of my file, I put a reference to the `tsd.d.ts` like this:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
```

The require is defined like this as of January 2016:

```
declare var require: NodeRequire;

interface NodeModule {
    exports: any;
    require: NodeRequireFunction;
    id: string;
    filename: string;
    loaded: boolean;
    parent: any;
    children: any[];
}
```

Comment: I got 404 not found

Answer (score 5):

I took [Peter Varga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263434/441662) to add `declare var require: any;` and made it into a generic solution that works for all .ts files generically by using the [preprocess-loader](https://github.com/artificialtrends/preprocess-loader):

1. install preprocessor-loader:

   ```
   npm install preprocessor-loader
   ```
2. add the loader to your *webpack.config.js* (I'm using [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader) for processing TypeScript sources):

```js
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader!preprocessor?file&config=preprocess-ts.json'
        }]
    }
```

3. Add the configuration that will add the workaround to every source:

```js
{
    "line": false,
    "file": true,
    "callbacks": [{
        "fileName": "all",
        "scope": "source",
        "callback": "(function shimRequire(source, fileName) { return 'declare var require: any;' + source; })"
    }]
}
```

---

You can add the more robust *require.d.ts* the same way, but `declare var require: any;` was sufficient in my situation.

Note, [there's a bug in preprocessor 1.0.5](https://github.com/artificialtrends/preprocess-loader/issues/1), which cuts off the last line, so just make sure you have an extra line space return at the end and you'll be fine.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It answers the question and brings something new and significant to the table. Now you don't have to mangle every file individually to satisfy the transpiler and webpack.

Comment: Can you explain step 3 more? I'm a newb and don't know where to put this configuration code at.

Comment: @user441058, checkout the [GitHub page](https://github.com/artificialtrends/preprocess-loader), step 3 is about the main configuration for the preprocess-loader.

Answer (score 5):

For me it is resolved by adding **types** to the angular compiler options.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
"fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
"strictInjectionParameters": true,
"types": [ "node" ]
}
```

Comment: It's in tsconfig.json for anyone wants to know.

Comment: this is for angular 9.

Answer (score 4):

I've yet another answer that builds upon all previous ones that describe `npm install @types/node` and including `node` in `tsconfig.json / compilerOptions / types`.

In my case, I have a base `tsConfig.json` and a separate one in the Angular application that extends this one:

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
        "types": []
 },
```

My problem was the empty `types` in this `tsconfi.app.json` - it clobbers the one in the base configuration.

Answer (score 4):

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'
```

Answer (score 4):

As approved answer didn't mention possibility to actually create your own typings file, and import it there, let me add it below.

Assuming you use npm as your package manager, you can:

```
npm i @types/node --save-dev
```

Then in your tsconfig file:

### tsconfig.json

```
"include": ["typings.d.ts"],
```

Then create your typings file:

### typings.d.ts

```
import 'node/globals'
```

Done, errors are gone, enjoy TypeScript :)

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling from this issue as well. I believe that this works for all *release candidates* aka *rc* but I didn't test it though. For **@angular rc.2** it works well.

1. Add `core-js` as npm dependency in `package.json`
2. run `typings install core-js --save`
3. remove all `"es6-shim"` occurances in your `package.json`. You don't need it anymore.

Cheers!

Comment: what is the core-js typings for? specific to node?

Answer (score 2):

Sometime missing "jasmine" from tsconfig.json may cause this error. **(TypeScript 2.X)**

So add

```
"types": [
  "node",
  "jasmine"
]
```

to your `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

[Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)) + Angular 2/4 addition:

On top of adding the 'node' type to ts.config various files, what eventually worked for me was adding the next to the
`typings.d.ts` file:

```
declare var window: Window;
interface Window {
  process: any;
  require: any;
}
```

Note that my case is developing with Electron + Angular 2/4. I needed the require on the window global.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you specify what module to use to transpile the code?
   `tsc --target es5 --module commonjs script.ts`
   You must do that to let the transpiler know that you're compiling NodeJS code. [Docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Modules.md#code-generation-for-modules).
2. You must install mongoose definitions as well
   `tsd install mongoose --save`
3. Do not use `var` to declare variables (unless necessary, which is a very rare case),  use `let` instead.  [Learn more about that](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the 'require' error to go away by using any of the tricks above.

But I found out that the issue was that my TypeScript tools for Visual Studio where an old version (1.8.6.0) and the latest version as of today is (2.0.6.0).

You can download the latest version of the tools from:

*[TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593)*

Answer (score 1):

Just in addition to cgatian's answer, for **TypeScript 1.x**

If you are still seeing errors, please specifically provide index.d.ts in your compiler options.

```
"files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can compile code, but Visual Studio 2015 marks 'require' functions as errors with error text *cannot find name 'require'* or *cannot resolve symbol 'require'*, update TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015 to the latest version (at the moment 2.1.5) and update ReSharper (if you use it) to at least version 2016.3.2.

I had this annoying problem for a while and couldn't find a solution, but I finally resolved it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ]
```

Comment: This is already mentioned in @cgatian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35961176/5524090).

Comment: @cgatian has mentioned "node_modules/@types" while I mentioned "../node_modules/@types".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed `npm i @types/node`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Yarn v3 and see this error (cannot find name require) or other node related "cannot find" errors in VSCode, make sure you have Yarn's VSCode sdk plugin installed and have selected the workspace version of Typescript.

Command to install the sdks:

```
yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks
```

To set the Typescript version:

1. Select a Typescript file
2. Press Command + Shift + P
3. Type Typescript: Select Typescript Version

- Select "Use Workspace Version"

See https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks#vscode for more details.

Answer (score -2):

If you are facing this issue in a .ts file which is only there to provide you some constant values, then you can just

> rename your .ts file to .js file

and the error will not come again.

Comment: Renaming my ts file to js works! It seems it's a hack but it's a personal project so I'll just let that be. You may also need to add "allowJs": true in under compilerOptions in your tsconfig file.