# TypeScript + Node-Webkit : need compiler to ignore "error" of importing External module in Internal module

Tags: module, typescript, node-webkit, nw.js

Good day. I'm using [Node-Webkit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/) with TypeScript to develop a proof of concept cross-platform desktop app. Node-Webkit is Webkit with builtin Node , which allows me to use Node apis via `import require` and use Webkit for UI (think Apache Cordova \ Phonegapp), both run in the same process, so you can just `import` in your ViewControllers \ Services). IDE is VS 2015 Community with Node Tools 1.1

My problem is, I have an Internal module with an AngularJS controller, like you would expect in a browser, but it imports node "fs" and "path" modules to save data on local file system. There are two options:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/node/node.d.ts" />

// Works fine, but TS does not recognize it as module import,
// thus,  no Intellisense and type checking    
var path = require("path");

// TS recognizes module import and provides binding, 
// but gives an error "Import declarations in an 
// internal module cannot reference an external module" 
// and WILL NOT COMPILE to JS
import path = require("path");
```

A quick workaround for me has been to develop with `import` and then change to `var` just before saving.

Can anybody please tell me how to do one of the following:

1. Supress this particular warning and make the file compile (ideally, supress at file level)?
2. Get a d.ts file for this specific scenario? I might later try to convert an existing node.d.ts, but maybe someone has done it already?
3. Some other workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CommonJS modules in your project and combine them with [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Another option to use CommonJS is to sham require function:

```
var require = function (oldRequire: (moduleName: string) => any) {
    return (moduleName: string) =>
        exports.sham.modules[moduleName].exports || oldRequire(moduleName);
} (require);
```

write at beginning of each of your module:

```
exports.sham("yourModule");
```

and in a referencing module:

```
import yourModule = require("yourModule")
```

See the [gist](https://gist.github.com/ArtemAvramenko/aafa156df5a2f8956245).

Answer (score 0):

I would completely abandod internal module system, it was simply *pain* when I was trying to make it work. I gave them up and being happy ever since. ;)

And if you use modules you'd better run forward: use ES6 import statement everywhere and compile back to ES5 with commonjs / amd modules (for node / requirejs respectively) until we have native ES6 import support.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who looks for this after the release of TypeScript 2 (September 2016), just install `@types/node`, also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35961176/7197182) for more information.