# VS2015 Typescript Cannot find name 'require'

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I installed [Node.js tools for Visual Studio](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/releases) and created a new TypeScript > Node.js > Blank Node.js console application project.

Currently I only have one file (sender.ts). Code below:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(); //creates a new client

client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected');
});

client.on('ready', function () { 
    client.publish('agent', 'I am sending a message.');
});
```

When I build the project, I get a compilation error ***Cannot find name 'require'.*** on line 1.

Can anyone help in explaining why this happens and how I can fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require#answer-31263434

Comment: At first that answer didn't solve my problem, but I must have changed something. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
import redis = require('redis');
```

or

```
import redis from 'redis';
```