# Angular 2 Typescript compilation error TS2304?

Tags: typescript, angular

Having error TS2304 during typescript build for all the references of `module.id` in all of my components definitions. Definition looks like this:

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'sd-app',
   =>   moduleId: module.id,
        templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavbarComponent, FooterComponent],
        providers: [AuthService]
    })
```

Here is the error:

```
app\components\app.component.ts(15,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
```

Compilation completes and application works fine though.

Any idea how to get rid of this error?

Comment: It would help to give the code that the error is referencing.

Comment: Try `declare var module: any`?

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to declare it globally, rather repeating in each component definition?

Comment: @Nexus23 that should work if you add that line in your main file (let's say `bootstrap.ts`), but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typescript getting error TS2304: cannot find name ' require'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'

Because TypeScript cannot see the variable `module` declared anywhere.

## Quickfix

Create a `globals.d.ts` with the following:

```
declare var module:any;
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks Basarat. I have put the globals.d.ts in my angular application root location which is the typescript files location for compilation as well.