# Install npm package that does not have typings

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I am using Typescript 2.1. I am trying to install an npm package that doesn't have typings (`reactable`).

If I do:

`import * as Reactable from 'reactable'` typescript complains that cannot find this module.

If I do:

`const Reactable = require('reactable')` typescript complains that `require` is forbidden.

If I do the weird syntax that suggested in another post:

`import Reactable = require('reactable');` typescript complains that `import` assignment cannot be used to target es2015 modules.

Is there any way to import npm packages that do not have typings?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [TS2304](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require)? Have you tried `declare var require: any`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to declare something about what you're using.
For example

```
declare module "reactable" {
    interface ReactableProps {
        ....
    }

    interface ReactableState {
        ....
    }

    class reactable extends React.Component< ReactableProps, ReactableState> { }
}
```

You can start with just what you're using and need the IDE to support, and slowly add things up.

You can check the [Writing Declaration Files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) for more info on how to do so.