# how to use a json file in a typescript file

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a file called men.json.

I want to do the equivalent of `var men = require('./men.json');`.

Whatever I have tried it looks for `./men.json.js` file.

I read that I can not use `import` since it is not a `ts` file.

What is the equivalent required line?

Answer (score 2):

```
declare module '*.json' {
    var _: any;
    export default _;
}
```

then you can `import mem from './mem.josn'`

put this into some file that's included in `tsconfig.json`

now you can require `.json`, this works for any other file formats (though you need webpack since nodejs cannot require them directly)

Answer (score 0):

You should try requiring as follows:

```
// foo.ts
var mem = require('./mem.json);
console.log(mem);
```

Then compile ...

```
tsc foo.ts
```

This will give a generic typescript error, like:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require

which you could ignore ... or preferably, get rid of by installing the necessary typings - or package if you are using typescript 2 or later. (see [typescript getting error TS2304: cannot find name ' require'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require))