# angular-seed-advanced: error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UnderscoreStatic'

Tags: angular, typescript, underscore.js, typescript-typings, everlive

I'm trying to integrate [Everlive SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/everlive-sdk) with [Angular seed advanced](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced). The SDK is version 1.9.1. It should work seamlessly after adding the typings from the npm package, but when trying to build the project there is that error:

> /node_modules/everlive-sdk/dist/declarations/everlive/Everlive.d.ts(88,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UnderscoreStatic'.

I have tried installing Underscore typings both from DefinetlyTyped repo and from EverliveSDK package as well.

Is there any chance this is problem with the config for TypeScript compiler?
Any suggestions what it might be at all?

Comment: Sounds like typings not installed. Check for a typings folder in your project.

Comment: Yep, it's there. I have Underscore installed there from Everlive SDK distribution.

Comment: May be this will help you ---> [typescript getting error TS2304: cannot find name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35961176/4816207)

Comment: Tried _npm install --save @types/underscore_ but the error persists. I suspect that it might be because of the tsconfig. Is it possible to not include the typings?

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging I've found the issue. The seed was using Gulp and in the tasks was hardcoded to search for typings not in "./typings", but instead in some other random sub-directory. After changing the path, it worked.