# NPM-MQTT Angular2 require

Tags: node.js, angular, mqtt

I am having trouble integrating https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt into my angular2 typescript project (created with angular-cli).

Using `var mqtt = require('mqtt');` produces the error `Cannot find name 'require'`

Therefore I tried using import (as I normally would) by adding it to the modules.ts:

```
import { mqtt } from 'mqtt/mqtt';

...
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    mqtt
],
```

I tried this with `import { MQTT } from 'mqtt/mqtt';` and `import { MqttClient } from 'mqtt/mqtt';` as well (the last one is exported as such in the mqtt.js

I even tried importing those in the classfile itself.

I am pretty sure this is a trivial error on my behalf but I cannot get my head around it.

(Note: "@types/node": "^7.0.0", is installed as well, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require) won't work either)

my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/browser",
        "typings/browser.d.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "buildOnSave": false,
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false,
        "formatOnSave": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the angular-cli or are you managing all of the webpack/ts config stuff manually?

Comment: yes, I am using angular-cli. I did webpack 1 month ago and switched recently.

Answer (score 0):

The import statement is incorrect; in case you're importing from a generic Javascript module from a Typescript file, you can import all of it - this works with any Javascript library that has some exports:

```
import * as mqtt from 'mqtt';
let client = mqtt.connnect('mqtt://hostname.example.com');
```

And in case the module was written in Typescript, or has typings that you also have added to your `devDependencies` in `package.json`, you could import some of the exported fields:

```
import { connect } from 'mqtt';
let client = connect('mqtt://hostname.example.com');
```

In case of this very module, it seems it has typings built in, so you can import specific parts of the module.

In your example, you're actually tring to import an `mqtt` symbol from the `mqtt` subfolder of the `mqtt` module, which probably does not exist and thus fails.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation it has suggested how to use it in ts [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt)

```
import { connect } from 'mqtt';
const client  = connect('wxs://test.mosquitto.org');
```