# Using a browserified JS library with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, browserify

I want to use libquassel (https://github.com/magne4000/node-libquassel) in my Angular 2 project. The library is browserified, so in theory it should work, but I'm not really sure how to import it in my project.

I tried adding to my `typings.d.ts`

```
declare module 'libquassel';
```

and then importing the library with

```
import * as Quassel from 'libquassel';
```

but I get

```
EXCEPTION: net.Socket is not a function
```

when I try to run my code, which I believe is another library that browserify embedded in the `client/libquassel.js` file.

How can I use this library?

**Edit**: I'll answer all questions here:

- My setup is a plain angular-cli project. No fancy stuff, just `ng new proj1` and then `npm install libquassel --save`.
- My `index.html` doesn't have anything else that `ng new` hasn't placed in there.
- I tried importing the library with `import * as Quassel from 'libquassel'` and `var Quassel = require('quassel')` (and permutations of those), without any luck (errors varying from `unknown function 'require'` to `can't find module lib|quassel`).
- Steps to repro my project:

  ```
  ng new test
  cd test
  npm install libquassel --save
  ng g s quassel
  ```

Then add `QuasselService` to the `providers` array in `app.module.ts`.
This would be a good demo of my problem, which is how to import `libquassel` in my `QuasselService`.

Comment: Can you give more detail about your setup? What does your index.html looks like? Are you using angular-cli? How do you import this module?

Comment: @echonax Check my edit. You can also reproduce my project, since this is just a plain angular-cli project.

Comment: update your post with the configuration file you have

Comment: @Aravind which configuration file?

Comment: systemjs or webpack?

Comment: @Aravind Please be more descriptive with your questions. As I already said, this is an angular-cli project (generated with `ng new`), so I don't really understand your question.

Comment: my question is very straight update post with config file what ever configuration you are using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138469/discussion-between-alexandernst-and-aravind).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update** (fix it, this time for real)

There is a very good reason why it doesn't work in your code: because I lied to you. So here is my real cheat in case you didn't "diffed" it yourself yet.

I still need to `require` libquassel 2 times but the first time is done not by the call to `require` which is useless but by adding it to `angular-cli.json` to the `scripts` section:

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/libquassel/client/libquassel.js"
  ],
```

This is important because "client/libquassel.js" declares its own `require` but do not explicitly exports it so if you do

```
require('libquassel/client/libquassel.js');
```

libquassel's custom `require` is left stuck inside anonymous namespace and you can't access it. Adding it to the `scripts` section on the other hand, lets libquassel.js to pollute the global namespace (i.e. `window`) with its `require` and thus make it work.

So the actual steps to make it work are:

1. Add client/libquassel.js to the scripts `section` of `angular-cli.json`
2. Use additional `require` to actually load `Quassel` module

```
let Quassel = window['require']('quassel'); // note that usingg require('quassel') leads to compilation error
let quasselObj = new Quassel(...);
```

---

Here is my attempt. It looks like you need to `require` "quassel" 2 times: first time to load the JS from "../node_modules/libquassel/client/libquassel.js" and second time to let the overridden `require` from that JS actually resolve "quassel". Here is a trick that seems to work for me in 'main.ts':

```
require('../node_modules/libquassel/client/libquassel.js');
let Quassel = window['require']('quassel'); // note that using require('quassel') leads to compilation error
let quasselObj = new Quassel(...);
```

I needed one more trick to not fail with a compilation error: particularly I had to use `window['require']` instead of just `require` for the second call as it is a call for the inner `require` as defined inside `client/libquassel.js` and Node/Angular-cli alone can't handle it.

Note that after that setup my application still failed with a runtime error in some AJAX because browsified `libquassel.js` seem to require a proxy set up on the server-side at URL like `/api/vm/net/connect` and this is probably what server-side of the [net-browsify](https://github.com/emersion/net-browserify) should do but I didn't try to set it up.

**Answer to comments**

It looks like you use old version of Angular-CLI and if you upgrade everything should work fine.

Here is what `ng --version` tells me on my original machine

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 6.10.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10
```

When I tried to copy my original project to a different machine I also got a compilation error about `require` but when I updated Angular-CLI to

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 6.10.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10
```

it compiled and worked the same. What I did is just followed the instruction

> The package "angular-cli" has been deprecated and renamed to "@angular/cli".
>
> Please take the following steps to avoid issues: 
>   "npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli" 
>   "npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"

and then updated `angular-cli.json` following the instructions by `ng serve`

Comment: This looks good! Don't worry about the AJAX error you're getting, that happens because you need a specially crafted expressjs server listening.

Comment: I'm finally at home and I'm testing your code, but I get this: `src/app/quassel-client.service.ts (6,1): Cannot find name 'require'`.

Comment: @alexandernst, I'm not at my code right now but where do you get it? Is it a compilation error for the line `require('../node_modules/libquassel/client/libquassel.js');` or is it a runtime error for `let Quassel = window['require']('quassel')`?

Comment: It's a compilation code at the require line. So, basically, the compiler doesn't know what "require" is.

Comment: @alexandernst, it looks like the difference is that you use some old Angular-CLI and upgrade should fix it. See my update in the main answer.

Comment: I updated my angular-cli (it now shows cli 1.0.0, node 7.7.2 and @angular/xyz 2.4.9), but I keep getting the error.

Comment: I also tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/35961176/940158 but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: @alexandernst, to test is that a difference between projects or between environments, could you try my project? I uploaded zip-ed folder to http://dropmefiles.com/X3Sbo (if you update angular, you might need to update angular-cli.json but it is trivial: just change 3 lines as instruction by `ng server` suggests)

Comment: It works with your project, so there is definitely something wrong with mine. I'll debug it by diffing yours. Since this is the cleanest solution (imho), I'm accepting it. Thank you for the help and kudos for the great answer!

Comment: @alexandernst, There is a very good reason why it doesn't work in your code: because I lied to you. I think I found what really makes my project work. See update in the question and let me know if this still doesn't work for you for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Works like a charm :

```
declare var require;
const Quassel = require( 'libquassel/lib/libquassel.js' );
console.log( 'Quassel', Quassel );
```

Looking at the `libquassel`'s folder in node_module, realised that there is no `index.js` in the root directory.

When there is not `index.js` , you **can't** do this :

```
 require( 'libquassel' );
```

Simply because node doesn't know what to pull in for you, so you'd need to specify the exact path, which is not that bad in this case.

Also , note that it's better to move `declare var require;`  to your typings file located under the src folder, because you might need to declare it again , so it's better be there.

EDIT : 
Here is what I found after trying to instantiate the Quassel like bellow :

```
const Quassel = require( 'libquassel/lib/libquassel.js' );
console.log( 'Quassel', Quassel );
var quassel = new Quassel( "quassel.domain.tld",
    4242,
    { backloglimit : 10 },
    function ( next ) {
        next( "user", "password" );
    } );
console.log( 'quassel', quassel );
```

And here is my console log :

[image]
But having said that, I realised that there is a problem inside the libquassel.js , as bellow :

in line 10, they're doing this :

```
   var net = require('net');
```

And looking their package.json, there is no such a thing as `net` and there is `net-browserify-alt`;

So if they change that import to :

```
 var net = require('net-browserify-alt'),
```

Everything will work.

Having said that, obviously you don't want to edit your node_module, but I'm really surprised of how this really works even outside of angular and webpack , because clearly they've mentioned a wrong node_module which if you google , there is only one package named `net` which I had a look and it's empty and dummy !!!!

** ********** UPDATE : ********** **

What exactly needs to be done :

1- run  `ng eject`

that will generate a `webpack.conf.js` inside your root directory.

2- inside that find `resolve` property and add :

```
 "alias":{
     'net':'net-browserify-alt'
  },
```

so your resolve will probably look like :

```
"resolve": {
    "extensions": [
      ".ts",
      ".js"
    ],
      "alias":{
         'net':'net-browserify-alt'
      },
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules"
    ]
  },
```

3-  import and use it :

```
declare var require;
const Quassel = require( 'libquassel/lib/libquassel.js' );
console.log( 'Quassel', Quassel );
var quassel = new Quassel( "quassel.domain.tld",
    4242,
    { backloglimit : 10 },
    function ( next ) {
        next( "user", "password" );
    } );
console.log( 'quassel', quassel );
```

---

NOTE :

Having a look at webpack configuration, seems like webpack likes to override couple of modules :

```
"node": {
    "fs": "empty",
    "global": true,
    "crypto": "empty",
    "tls": "empty",
    "net": "empty",
    "process": true,
    "module": false,
    "clearImmediate": false,
    "setImmediate": false
  }
```

I don't exactly know why, but this list is in the webpack config and seems to be making `net` to be undefiend ( empty ) and that's why we had to create an alias.

Comment: By requiring the node version (`lib/libquassel.js`) instead of the browserified version (`client/libquassel.js`) I'm not really sure typescript´s compiler/webpack/whatever will be able to properly replace `net` with `net-browserify`. That said, did you actually try to instantiate `Quassel` after doing the `require(".....client/libquassel.js")`? I mean, are you able to actually run `var foo = new Quassel();`?

Comment: `net` is an internal node.js module ( https://nodejs.org/api/net.html )

Comment: @alexandernst , try my update , it works fully in my local

Comment: Now that looks interesting! Please give me a couple of days to test it (I`m not at home right now).

Comment: There are more than mappings required than just `net-browserify-alt`, so make sure you look in `Gruntfile.js` for the full list

Comment: @KScandrett , not sure about should we map all of them or not, the problem is that webpack exclude couple of specific node modules and net was one of them

Comment: Some of the standard Node modules won't run in a web browser, only in Node. That's why there is the `net` to `net-browserify-alt` mapping - so that it will run within a browser. The OP will need to include all of these mappings

Comment: If you look at the browserefied https://github.com/magne4000/node-libquassel/blob/master/client/libquassel.js you'll notice that there are more than 100 dependencies inside (search for `124:`). I don't think that mapping them all by hand is a good idea. Actually this is probably why they created a separate browserefied JS in the first place

Comment: But do we need to map those? Seems to be working without mapping them though.

Comment: @Milad, what do you mean by "working". Are you able to do `quassel.connect` successfully? Or just create a new object (which is by far not enough)? Do you get a real connection? Or at least do you get AJAX requests to your server? From what I see in the code, it looks like you need at least significant part of those dependencies to make it actually work.

Comment: @SergGr has a point here, mapping is probably a bad idea, since that is what Browserify is doing, and it's probably doing it better than us.

Comment: @SergGr , I've never used this library and to be honest I don't exactly know what it does, the question was about not being to import and initialise and that's what I've given an answer for.
But I'm more than happy to spend some time to end to end test.
Just give a scenario and a working example and I'll try to make it work in here

Comment: @Milad, you may notice that the example at the GitHub ends up with `quassel.connect();` and it is actually the key method of the API where many dependencies are actually used. I don't have any working example as working example requires also to setup a local server to listen to AJAX request from the browser to "proxy" them as actual Socket connections to IRC. Maybe @alexandernst has some example but still I doubt your code can even get to the part where first AJAX is sent not to mention parsing back "proxied" response

Comment: @Milad SergGr has a point here. Even if the map works for the net vs net-browserify module, the entire library is using tons and tons of libraries (mostly socket and net related stuff). I'm sure I'd get up to the point where I won't be able to use the library only by re-mapping modules. (basically, what I'm saying is that I don't think Browserify is just re-mapping modules, which is what we're trying to do here)

Answer (score 0):

Angular-cli uses webpack

you will need to add the JS file to apps[0].scripts in your angular-cli.json file, which WebPack then bundles as if it were loaded with a  tag.

```
apps:[
{
  ...
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/libquassel/client/libquassel.js"
  ],
```

If you do that, you can get at it by adding `declare var Quassel :any;` in your src/typings.d.ts or component.

```
let quassel = new Quassel("localhost", 4242, {}, function(next) {
  next("user", "password");
});
quassel.connect();
```

Comment: I get `EXCEPTION: Quassel is not defined`. And let me explain (for the 5th time in this post) that this is not a normal JS library that exports stuff, but a Browserify library that is supposed to be `require`d, and that is the reason why your solution doesn't work (and actually that is the reason why I assigned 500pts bounty to this question, as it's very tricky). If I load this library in a script tag, the one and only way I can access it is by doing `var Quassel = require("quassel")`.

Answer (score 0):

The key issue is the browserified `libquassel` library contains within it a global `require` function. That conflicts with standard `require` function.

There are many ways of handling this but one solution would be to copy `/libquassel/client/libquassel.js` (and the minified version) to your `/src/app/` directory.

Then run a search and replace in these files to change ALL occurrences of `require` to `_quasselRequire_`

You would do this for both `libquassel.js` and `libquassel.min.js`.

To utilise this you would do something like this in `quassel.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as dummyQuassel1 from './libquassel.js'

var dummyQuassel2 = dummyQuassel1; // something just to force the import

declare var _quasselRequire_ :any;

@Injectable()
export class QuasselService {

  constructor() { 

    // set up in the constructor as a demo

    let Quassel = _quasselRequire_( 'quassel' );
    console.log('Quassel', Quassel);

    var quassel = new Quassel( 
        "quassel.domain.tld",
        4242,
        { backloglimit : 10 },
        function ( next ) {
            next( "user", "password" );
        } 
    );

    console.log('quassel', quassel);

    quassel.on('network.init', function(networkId) {
        console.log("before net");
        var network = quassel.getNetworks().get(networkId);
        console.log("after net");
        // ...
    });

    console.log("before connect");
    quassel.connect();  
    console.log("after connect");
  }

  getQuassel() {
      return 'My Quassel service';
  }
}
```

This by itself results in the error:

> POST http://localhost:4200/api/vm/net/connect 404 (Not Found)

and

> Error: Uncaught, unspecified 'error' event.
>       at new Error (native)
>       at Quassel.n.emit (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:570:4210) [angular]
>       at Socket. (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:810:19931) [angular]
>       at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:573:1079) [angular] ...

But as I understand it this is fairly normal given I haven't Express etc. set up.

Note: the name `_quasselRequire_` can be anything that's appropriate to you.

Comment: As you probably are aware you'll also need to add the property `"allowJs": true` to `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.app.json`

Comment: If you're gonna do this, you'd probably need to write a script that does this because most of the time you install your dependencies, you don't touch them.
This is also bad from the upgrade point of view, if you even want to upgrade the package, you're screwed

Comment: Why would you be screwed?

Comment: @Milad has a valid point here, replacing stuff inside `node_module` is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @alexandernst I agree, but nowhere do I suggest replacing anything inside `node_module`. My suggestion above is to copy the final browserified script (libquassel/client/libquassel.[min].js) to your project's `/src/app/` first, and edit it there. Of course that could all be automated fairly easily

Comment: One could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader for instance, so Webpack grabs the latest version of the browserified library from `node_modules`, searches and replaces `require` with `_quasselRequire_` as it bundles

Comment: I think the only change needed above would then be to use something like `import * as dummyQuassel1 from 'libquassel/client/libquassel.js'`, so it doesn't even get copied to your `/src/app` dir, just pulled in, a "find and replace", all during the Webpack's build

Comment: If you've tried my manual steps in the answer and find it works correctly (like the others I don't have the full setup to test the IRC proxy) let me know and I'll happily update my answer with the automated steps addressing concerns in the comments.