# Angular 5 Service to read local .json file

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am using Angular 5 and I've created a service using the angular-cli

What I want to do is to create a service that reads a local json file for Angular 5.

This is what I have ... I'm a bit stuck...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AppSettingsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClientModule) {
    var obj;
    this.getJSON().subscribe(data => obj=data, error => console.log(error));
  }

  public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("./assets/mydata.json")
      .map((res:any) => res.json())
      .catch((error:any) => console.log(error));

  }

}
```

How can I get this finished?

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6 For example, `HttpClientModule` should not be injected in constructor.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

First You have to inject `HttpClient` and Not `HttpClientModule`, 
second thing you have to remove `.map((res:any) => res.json())` you won't need it any more because the new `HttpClient` will give you the body of the response by default , finally make sure that you import `HttpClientModule` in your `AppModule`
 :

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AppSettingsService {

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

    public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("./assets/mydata.json");
    }
}
```

to add this to your Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'mycmp',
    templateUrl: 'my.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private appSettingsService : AppSettingsService 
    ) { }

   ngOnInit(){
       this.appSettingsService.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting "Unresolved Type Observable" ... on this line "public getJSON(): Observable<any> {"

Comment: One last question ... How do I can this data from my component?

Comment: suppose if I want to read json id. What I have to do? Please if you dont mind provide me the example.

Comment: i have faced 404 error while fetching json file....and also follow same flow like yours..

Comment: I receive 404 with the log `GET http://localhost:4200/src/assets/data.json 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Also include "import { AppSettingsService } from '../app-settings.service';" in the above Component file

Comment: have you checked your code in prod environment..dont think we can read json or any file from asset folder like this. Code will work only on dev envrionemnt not prod.. ;)

Comment: those who get the 404, is mainly due to that there json file is not in assets folder, incase they you are required to move json file to any other directory then you need to add that in angular.json file

Comment: remove the 'src'  from the url, should start with 'assets/'

Answer (score 33):

For Angular 7, I followed these steps to directly import json data:

In tsconfig.app.json:

add `"resolveJsonModule": true` in `"compilerOptions"`

In a service or component:

```
import * as exampleData from '../example.json';
```

And then

```
private example = exampleData;
```

Answer (score 22):

You have an alternative solution, importing directly your json.

To compile, declare this module in your typings.d.ts file

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

In your code

```
import { data_json } from '../../path_of_your.json';

console.log(data_json)
```

Comment: Suppose, I have my json in assets/abc.json, and using only one module app.module.ts then how to declare in typing.d.ts and how to import. Please help.

Comment: Just declare the module in your typing.d.ts file. And import your JSON into your class

Comment: Which module?  Suppose I am using it in app. module. ts?

Comment: Second question,  module "*.json"?  You have written to declare what is this?  Is this a module name?

Comment: Hi. I'm getting  `error TS2305: Module '"*.json"' has no exported member 'data_json'.` when I'm trying to use this solution. Webpack compiles succsessfully, but the error is thrown on execution.

Comment: I got this to work without errors when I did `import { default as data_json } from '../../path_of_your.json';`

Comment: Same solution with an extended explanation: https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79

Comment: Why am I getting "undefined" in the console?

Answer (score 21):

I found this question when looking for a way to really read a local file instead of reading a file from the web server, which I'd rather call a "remote file".

Just call `require`:

```
const content = require('../../path_of_your.json');
```

The Angular-CLI source code inspired me: I found out that they include component templates by replacing the `templateUrl` property by `template` and the value by a `require` call to the actual HTML resource.

If you use the AOT compiler you have to add the node type definitons by adjusting `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "types": ["node"],
  ...
},
...
```

Comment: To use `require` I needed to install `@types/node` by running `npm install @types/node --save-dev` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35961176/4463445)

Comment: all these solutions are great, but this is one of the only ones that will allow me to save the values and parse the file content dynamically without an initial import

Answer (score 15):

Assumes, you have a data.json file in the src/app folder of your project with the following values:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Licensed Frozen Hat",
        "description": "Incidunt et magni est ut.",
        "price": "170.00",
        "imageUrl": "https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?product",
        "quantity": 56840
    },
    ...
]
```

## 3 Methods for Reading Local JSON Files

#### Method 1: Reading Local JSON Files Using TypeScript 2.9+ import Statement

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as data from './data.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<ul>
      <li *ngFor="let product of products">

      </li>
  </ul>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Angular Example';

  products: any = (data as any).default;

  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

#### Method 2: Reading Local JSON Files Using Angular HttpClient

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<ul>
      <li *ngFor="let product of products">

      </li>
  </ul>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Angular Example';
  products: any = [];

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.httpClient.get("assets/data.json").subscribe(data =>{
      console.log(data);
      this.products = data;
    })
  }
}
```

#### Method 3: Reading Local JSON Files in Offline Angular Apps Using ES6+ import Statement

If your Angular application goes offline, reading the JSON file with HttpClient will fail. In this case, we have one more method to import local JSON files using the ES6+ import statement which supports importing JSON files.

But first we need to add a typing file as follows:

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

Add this inside a new file `json-typings.d.ts` file in the src/app folder.

Now, you can import JSON files just like TypeScript 2.9+.

```
import * as data from "data.json";
```

Comment: In tsconfig.app.json file, need to add `"resolveJsonModule": true` in "compilerOptions". otherwise there will be error like - `Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension`

Answer (score 7):

```
import data  from './data.json';
export class AppComponent  {
    json:any = data;
}
```

See this article for [more details](https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/loading-json-on-stackblitz-with-angular-bf77a1da3f8a).

Comment: For my local file this was easiest to use. I had to add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to my tsconfig.json 'compilerOptions', but only to stop a linting error for TypeScript, NOT an actual error.

Comment: This is the solution: https://hackeruna.com/2020/04/27/error-with-angular-8-and-9-allowsyntheticdefaultimports-flag-error-ts1259/ for this error TS1259

Answer (score 6):

Try This

Write code in your service

```
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
```

import json file

```
import Product  from "./database/product.json";

getProduct(): Observable<any> {
   return of(Product).pipe(delay(1000));
}
```

In component

```
get_products(){
    this.sharedService.getProduct().subscribe(res=>{
        console.log(res);
    })        
}
```

Comment: Best answer to the moment for the ones that are not able to add "resolveJsonModule": true into their tsconfig

Answer (score 3):

Using Typescript 3.6.3, and Angular 6, none of these solutions worked for me.

What *did* work was to follow the tutorial [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-read-local-json-files-deploy-an-angular-app-a96a881036f2) which says you need to add a small file called `njson-typings.d.ts` to your project, containing this:

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

Once this was done, I could simply import my hardcoded json data:

```
import employeeData from '../../assets/employees.json';
```

and use it in my component:

```
export class FetchDataComponent implements OnInit {
  public employees: Employee[];

  constructor() {
    //  Load the data from a hardcoded .json file
    this.employees = employeeData;
    . . . .
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let’s create a JSON file, we name it navbar.json you can name it whatever you want!

**navbar.json**

```
[
  {
    "href": "#",
    "text": "Home",
    "icon": ""
  },
  {
    "href": "#",
    "text": "Bundles",
    "icon": "",
    "children": [
      {
        "href": "#national",
        "text": "National",
        "icon": "assets/images/national.svg"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now we’ve created a JSON file with some menu data. We’ll go to app component file and paste the below code.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import menudata from './navbar.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'lm-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html'
})
export class NavbarComponent {
    mainmenu:any = menudata;

}
```

Now your Angular 7 app is ready to serve the data from the local JSON file.

Go to app.component.html and paste the following code in it.

**app.component.html**

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let menu of mainmenu">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{{menu.href}}">{{menu.icon}} {{menu.text}}</a>
                  <ul class="sub_menu" *ngIf="menu.children && menu.children.length > 0"> 
                            <li *ngFor="let sub_menu of menu.children"><a class="nav-link" href="{{sub_menu.href}}"><img src="{{sub_menu.icon}}" class="nav-img" /> {{sub_menu.text}}</a></li> 
                        </ul>
                  </li>
                  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it didn't work when I try to import the data file. instead, I have moved the data file to the assets folder and tried to access it through get request.

```
 public getProjectTree()
   {
      return this.http.get("assets/data.json");
   }
```