# .json file not recognised using http.get?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to access input data that's stored inside of a `.json` file but for some reason my path isn't recognised:

This method runs when data is requested:

```
    getData() {
  console.log('this is working');
  this.http.get('src/app/inputs/inputs.json')
  .subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      console.log('this is working');
      console.log(data.text());
     }
   );
  }
}
```

This is my folder structure:

[image]

I am able to add the data whenever a separate button is clicked, just retrieving it is where I get stuck.

Comment: use ng-resource

Comment: How do I do this specifically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5 Service to read local .json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206924/angular-5-service-to-read-local-json-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to add your inputs folder in the assets section of angular.json
eg

```
"assets": [
  "src/assets",
  "src/inputs",
  "src/favicon.ico"
]
```

then access your data through

```
this.http.get('inputs/inputs.json')
```

Comment: I'd asked to moved `.json` to `assets` since it is going to be static asset ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.http.get('./inputs/inputs.json')`

Comment: Which file contains this function?

Comment: app.component.ts

Comment: If you're using angular-cli, you must put your file.json in the assets/folder. Angular-cli cleate a index.html, style.css and severals .js and copy all the files in folder assets