# Basic use of JSON in Angular

Tags: json, angular

How do I get the information from a JSON file to iterate in my Angular project?

I want to import the information from my JSON file. I do not know how to include the JSON file into an array.

I want the words `"Abbey", "Abbeyard", "Abbeywood"`.... and so on to show up.

I have my JSON file in the same directory as my component.

Here is my JSON *code*

```
[
  {
    "ABBA RIVER": "ABBEY",
  },
  {
    "ABBA RIVER": "ABBEYARD",
  },
  {
    "ABBA RIVER": "ABBEYWOOD",
  }

...
```

Comment: its a simple array of Objects . You can loop through and access each object using the key 'ABBA RIVER'

Comment: This is a very basic question ;) Read up on `*ngFor`: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data if you are talking about template.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/47207063/2871326 if you wish to load json file

Comment: I think this is the solution that I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a good read of [Angular - Displaying Data](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data)

In your Component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  abbas = [{
    "ABBA RIVER": "ABBEY",
  },
  {
    "ABBA RIVER": "ABBEYARD",
  },
  {
    "ABBA RIVER": "ABBEYWOOD",
  }];
}
```

In your Template:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let abba of abbas">
      {{ abba["ABBA RIVER"] }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

To get the JSON from a file:

[Angular 5 Service to read local .json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206924/angular-5-service-to-read-local-json-file/47207063#47207063)

Answer (score -1):

I agree with CruelEngine.
You can write plain javascript code in any version of angular. Therefore I am providing you a code where I am looping through Json and fetching the data that I need.

```
var _shapes=ObjectToBeConvertedIntoJson;
if ((_shapes != undefined)) {

    var shapesJsonData = JSON.parse(_shapes);
    for (var keyAttr in shapesJsonData) {
        var valDataRow = shapesJsonData[keyAttr];
        var attrs = valDataRow.attrs;
}
}
```