# Import static JSON file from assets dir in component (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am using Angular CLI (version 6).
I have a small `JSON` file in my `assets` folder which I want to import into my component. I want to do this **without** using a GET request from my component.

What I did:

- I created a new file, `typings.d.ts`:

  ```
  declare module "*.json" {
      const value: any;
      export default value;
  }
  ```

  ... and referred to it in `tsconfig.spec.json`. Here is a snippet of the referral in `ts.config.spec.json`:

  ```
  "files": [
      "test.ts",
      "polyfills.ts",
       "./typings.d.ts"
  ],
  ```
- From my component, I am trying to import my JSON file as such:

  ```
  import * as myConfig from '../../assets/config.json';
  ```

At that line however, I get an error message: `cannot find module ../../assets/config.json`.

I am quite sure that this relative path is correct (I tried several other options as well, similarly for the typings.d.ts referral - but anyway, my directory structure is just a simple Angualr CLI app:

```
|- src
    |   
    |-app
    |   |-component
    |       |-component.ts
    |
    |
    |-assets
        |-config.json
```

Any tips on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: visit this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206924/angular-5-service-to-read-local-json-file/65967378#65967378

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just `import myConfig from 'path/to/json'` then use it in your file.

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately: `Cannot find module '../../assets/config'.` (tried it with `.json` extension and also without)

Comment: [Here is the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypuy7b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: I have no clue why I received that error. But your method worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Moody it was probably the missing json extension, it was looking for a js file by default

Comment: @Moody you may need to set `"resolveJsonModule": true` in `ts.config` see [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-2-9-2/#json-imports)

Comment: I had exactly the same problem with Angular 11. In tsconfig.json I had to replace     "baseUrl": "./"  by  "baseUrl": "src"  and I had to add
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true,
- then it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is:

1. Give the structure a name (json, xml, whatever) :

   `export const myJson =  { "_id":"1234", "name":"John" }`

2. Change the file extension to "**.ts**"
3. Finally import the file

   `import { myJson } from 'src/my-static-file';`

   `public json = myJson;`

Comment: nice little hack, thank you :)

Comment: But then it's not a JSON anymore, it's a typescript file. In my case we need it for angular and for external applications so we want to keep it as a json asset

Answer (score 2):

The new file you added should be named `json-typings.d.ts` with the following code:

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

Put it in your src folder (the same directory as `index.html`)

Then import JSON files in your component:

`import * as SampleJson from "../../assets/SampleJson.json";`

Also, you don't need to refer to it in `ts.config.spec.json`