# Angular - issue assigning json file to class

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm just wondering if you could help me fix this issue I'm having with assigning an interface from my json file. I am getting the ts error of json file is not assignable to type Data. 'data' is declared as a type of Data in the .ts file.

```
  this.data = '../assets/data.json';

  export interface Data {
      millers: Miller[];
  }

  export interface Miller {
      name: string;
      address: string;
      farms: Farm[];
  }

  export interface Farm {
     code: string;
     name: string;
     harvest: string;
     type: string;
     paddocks: Paddock[];
  }

  export interface Paddock {
     code: string;
     area: string;
     owner: string;
  }


  {
  "millers": [
    {
      "name": "Britney Houston",
      "address": "Summit Street Haena",
      "farms": [
        {
          "code": "deserunt840",
          "name": "Artiq",
          "harvest": "2012-06-26",
          "type": "Cane",
          "paddocks": [
            {
              "code": "do318",
              "area": 965
            },
```

Comment: It looks to me that you are setting data variable to a string, not a file value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented you're assigning a `string` value to a property that you've declared of type `Data`.

To fix it:

1. Make sure you have the following in `architect.build.options` in angular.json:

---

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
],
```

2. Create a `millers.json` file in `src/assets`.
3. Import `HttpClientModule` in your Module and add it to the `imports` array.
4. Inject `HttpClient` as a dependency in your Component and then use it's get method to call the `.json` which is sort of exposed as an API file:

---

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  data;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('../assets/millers.json')
      .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }
}
```

HEre's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-assigning-json-data?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

You can read JSON file using requirejs. Check this question for more details: [Angular 5 Service to read local .json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206924/angular-5-service-to-read-local-json-file).

---

`this.data = '../assets/data.json';`

This is your issue. All you're doing on this line assigning a `String` value to `this.data`. And as you mentioned `this.data` is of type `Data`, not string. Hence the error

Now, coming back to your issue, you cannot read data from JSON file (As far as I know.). If you have to, convert that JSON file into a .ts file and export your data from that file. then you can import it and assign to `this.data` or any other property