# How to read and display JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to open a local JSON file and have the information displayed on my app.

The code seems to run but the JSON information doesn't display.
How do I get the JSON information, name & age fields to display?

JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "name": "George",
        "age": "25"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sarah",
        "age": "42"
    }
]
```

App.js:

```
import * as myfile from './myfile.json'

const name = myfile.name;
const age = myfile.name;

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>This is name: {name} This is age: {age}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206924/angular-5-service-to-read-local-json-file

Comment: Try myfile[1].name.. its an array..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you are accessing an array, there is no `myfile.name` to assign to `const name`, you can, however, do something like this; `const name = myfile[0].name` for George's information only.

Conclusively, you are not extracting information properly from JSON.

P.S., if you can tell me what is the expected behavior, I can help you out.

Comment: Amazing! If I were to continue this JSON file with 100 entries, would I then simply continue the count to the corresponding entry? e.g [1],[2],[3]-[100]

Comment: Yes, you will have to extract that information. You can do in the following way: 

https://codesandbox.io/s/1vn9okn8kj

Comment: @axell2017 try it now.

Comment: Very good method. Will the JSON file require the "const JSON ="[ within it? Is there a way to do it without declaring any javascript in the JSON file? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `myFile` isn't an object but array.

Use the map array method:

```
...
 <View style={styles.container}>
       {myFile.map(({ name, age }) => (
        <Text>This is name: {name} This is age: {age}
        </Text>
       )}
 </View>
...

Hope that helped!
```