# Use data in html from local json file - typescript, angular 7

Tags: json, typescript, angular7

I want to import a simple local json file in my angular 7 project and use the data in my HTML file. Just a simple example. I have attached a json file as **data.json**. I want to access the data from this json file in **app.component.html** in place of **{{item}}**

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('detailsPanel') details;
  @ViewChild('displayDetails') displayDetails;


  // Need to access this data from a json file
  title = 'dragNdrop';
  todo = [
    'Get to work',
    'Pick up groceries',
    'Go home',
    'Fall asleep'
  ];

  done = [
    'Get up',
    'Brush teeth',
    'Take a shower',
    'Check e-mail',
    'Walk dog'
  ];

  elementDetails = "";

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        event.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }

  showDetails(text){
    this.elementDetails = text;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 2%;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="border-right: 1px solid black; height: 100%;">
      <div cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="todo" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
        class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div cdkDropList #doneList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="done" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList]"
        class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <p #detailsPanel class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of done" (click)="showDetails(detailsPanel.innerText)" cdkDrag>{{item}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**data.json**

```
{
    "list1": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes I will add right away

Comment: @SagarSamal Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206924/angular-5-service-to-read-local-json-file

Answer (score 0):

1. in

> tsconfig.json

add into "compilerOptions":

```
    "compilerOptions": 
    {
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
}
```

2. now you can import your data from your JSON in

> yourComponentFile.ts

thereby:

```
import { yourObject } from './data/yourJSON.json'
```

3. and to use

   dataImportedFromMyJson: any[] = yourObject;