# Angular 5 Service to read local .json file Error: Unknown compiler option 'resolveJsonModule' & 'esModuleInterop'

Tags: angular

i need to import local json file in angular but it is not find json extension i already resolveJsonModule & 'esModuleInterop' to true in tsconfig.json got unknown compiler option.

"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,

`````
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11
@angular/cdk: 5.2.5
@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular/material: 5.2.5
@angular/tsc-wrapped: 0.4.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tsconfig.json
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "include": [
    "./src"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./Scripts/Angular/out-tsc",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
  }
}

Error: 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tsconfig.json(9,5): error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'resolveJsonModule'.
tsconfig.json(10,5): error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'esModuleInterop'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------````
`````

Comment: After setting resolveJsonModule to true. Did you restart the VS code and localhost?

Comment: yes i checked it.

Comment: I guess you need to update typescript

Answer (score 0):

Typescript add `resolveJsonModule` in version 2.9 but you are using typescript 2.5.3 ([official doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule)).

Typescript add `esModuleInterop` in version 2.7 ([official doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#support-for-import-d-from-cjs-from-commonjs-modules-with---esmoduleinterop)).

As Typescript 2.9 is used from Angular 7, I don't know if you can update Typescript.

Maybe try another way like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47207063/3371440).