# Get data from .json file in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm building an app in angular 9 and I have a `.json` file to get data and I want to get first element.

I tried it from `take(1)`, `first` and `single()` but none worked.

How can we fetch data from `JSON` file?

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "username": "test",
    "password": "test",
    "firstName": "User",
    "lastName": "Test"
  },
  {
    "username": "test1",
    "password": "test1",
    "firstName": "User1",
    "lastName": "Test1"
  }
]
```

**Component.ts**

```
this.authenticationService.login()
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
      data => {
      console.log(data)
        if(this.loginModel.username == data.username && this.loginModel.password == data.password){
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(data));
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        }
        else{
          // this.error = error;
          // this.loading = false;
          alert('Please enter correct USERNAME OR PASSWORD');
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.error = error;
        this.loading = false;
      }
    );
```

Comment: Is the json file in your assets folder? Or where are you reading it from?

Comment: yes, in assets folder

Comment: So why don't you just import it and use it as an object?

Comment: please tell , as I am new to angular

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206924/angular-5-service-to-read-local-json-file

Comment: could you please put the result of console.log(data) in your question?

Comment: (2) [{…}, {…}]0: username: "test"password: "test"firstName: "User"lastName: "Test"__proto__: Object1: username: "test1"password: "test1"firstName: "User1"lastName: "Test1"__proto__: Objectlength: 2__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: If the data variable has the json file data, you can easily access to first object by data[0] or data[1]

Comment: yes, I can do it but how to do this by using rxjs methods like take or first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `json` file is in your assets folder, you can import it and use it as an object.

Here's what I do normally:

**JSON File**

```
{
   "LayerIds": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 11, 20, 21, 22, 23],
   "HiddenLayerIds": [3, 7, 11, 21, 20, 23],
   "DefinitionExpressionColumn": "vertical_order",
   "LevelId": 7,
   "LevelFilterOutFields": "vertical_order, name",
   "SelectedLayerId": 2,
   "LevelDictionary": ["vertical_order", "name"],
   "PathwaysLayerId": 22,
   "GeometryServiceAreaUnit": "square-feet",
   "GeometryServiceLengthUnit": "feet"
}
```

**Service.ts**

```
 import myJson from '../../../assets/json/config.json';

 readConfigFile() {
   return myJson;
 }
```

**Component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.mainConfiguration = this.service.readConfigFile();

   // This will print "feet" to the console
   console.log(this.mainConfiguration.GeometryServiceLengthUnit);
}
```

You can skip the `service` step and import the `json` file directly into your component.
But since you're using it as an object I think your `json` file should be like this:

```
{
 "Users": [
   {
     "username": "test",
     "password": "test",
     "firstName": "User",
     "lastName": "Test"
   },
   {
     "username": "test1",
     "password": "test1",
     "firstName": "User1",
     "lastName": "Test1"
   }]
}
```

In this way when you import the `json` file. Try `Console.log(importedjson.Users);` to see your data.

**NOTE:** If you built your application and got the following error:

`Cannot find module ‘../../assets/SampleJson.json’. Consider using ‘–resolveJsonModule’ to import module with ‘.json’ extension`

To remove the above error, in `tsconfig.json` file under compiler options we need to add `resolveJsonModule` and `esModuleInterop` configurations as true as shown below.

```
{  "compilerOptions": {  "resolveJsonModule": true, "esModuleInterop": true }}
```