# How get values and key in the object array JSON

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a JSON below :

```
{
  "sports": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Soccer" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Basketball" }
  ]
}
```

How I can read the id and the name in typeScript ? 
Currently  I use

```
let result = this.dataService.getJSON()

public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('./assets/json/data.json');
}
```

But I have a error message

```
map is not a function
```

I don't know How I can parse the JSON,

I would like have this result.

```
[
  { "id": 1, "name": "Soccer" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Basketball" }
]
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: There is no use of `map` in your code. Note that `result` is an `Observable<any>`, which I don't believe has a `map` function...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Is this related to Angular 2+?

Comment: [Angular 5 Service to read local .json file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47206924)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Observables, you need to subscribe for thread to receive a response:

```
this.dataService.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```