# How to download files from assets using HttpClient in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Based on previous answers to similar questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47207063/404604), downloading, or in general, reading files from the assets directory should be a straightforward call to `HttpClient`'s `get` method. For example if I have a `DownloadService`, I could simply define it as:

```
export class DownloadService {
    
  constructor(http: HttpClient){}

  download(data) {
    this.http.get('/assets/path/to/file.ext').subscribe(res => process(res));
  }

}
```

However, when I test this using `ng serve`, I get an error saying that `/assets/path/to/file.ext` is not a valid URL. I tried `./assets/path/to/file.ext`, and `assets/path/to/file.ext` but I got the same error. Do I need to configure something in the runtime to get this working properly, or has this changed since those answers were written? I'm using Angular 9.

Comment: did you console response? what is exact content?

Comment: I don't think it even gets to the point where I could process the response because it rejects the URL before it even attempts to execute the request.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs whenever you try to fetch something different than a JSON.
To fix it, please define the `responseType` accordingly. For example

```
this.http.get('./assets/path/to/file.txt', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(res => process(res));
```

Also, please notice how I've changed the URL, it should be `./assets/foo.bar`

Here's a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-l1cn5j

Just check the console :)

By the way, these are the accepted types for `responseType`:

```
responseType: 'arraybuffer'|'blob'|'json'|'text'
```

Answer (score -1):

I found out that the issue I was experiencing was due to a custom HTTP interceptor that assumes all URLs are valid URLs (file paths aren't). What I ended up doing to address this was to modify the interceptor to ignore URLs that are not valid.

Getting the asset to download using `HttpClient`'s `get` works as described.