# How to get json data from file using Observable

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am practicing reading data from a json file, which has a list of countries and states, before I have used this method, but I want to use httpClient and with tests I have these methods, but what is the correct way to read this data.
Earlie method:

```
  getCountries(): Observable<Country[]> {
    return of(countries['countries']);
  }
  getStates(countryID): Observable<State[]> {
    return of(countries['states'].filter(f => f.countryId === countryID));
  }
```

And this is a method how its work form me:

```
  getC(): Observable<Country[]> {
    return this.http.get<Country[]>(this.link).pipe(map(k => {
      return k['countries'];
    }));
  }
  getS(CID): Observable<State[]> {
    return this.http.get<State[]>(this.link).pipe(map(v => {
      return v['states'].filter(f => f.countryId === CID);
    }));
  }
```

I see something like this, but i have error

```
  getC3(): Observable<Country[]> {
    return this.http.get<Country[]>(this.link)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => <Country[]>res.countries)
      .then(data => {return data});
    }
```

how is right method to do this,
Error in :

[image: PromError]

It has been a few days, and it seems a serious problem, so I ask this side, what is the method to get data from this json:

```
  [
    {
      "data": [
        {
           "label": "Select State",
           "value": null
        },
        {
          "label": "Adeje",
          "value": {
             "county": "Gran Canaria",
             "state": "Islas Canarias",
             "country": "España"
           }
        },
        {
          "label": "Agaete",
          "value": {
            "county": "Gran Canaria",
            "state": "Islas Canarias",
            "country": "España"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
```

and how to get data from this json:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Select State",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "label": "Adeje",
    "value": {
      "county": "Gran Canaria",
      "state": "Islas Canarias",
      "country": "España"
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "Agaete",
    "value": {
      "county": "Gran Canaria",
      "state": "Islas Canarias",
      "country": "España"
    }
  }
]
```

considering that I use `--strict` mode

Comment: What error do you get (and where)?

Comment: I Modify my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5 Service to read local .json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206924/angular-5-service-to-read-local-json-file)

Comment: No because in this example is used <any> I wanna use class name

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure then what the correct type would be... I never appended types to `.get()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to recognize that the best practice while using angular is to use `Observables` rather that using `Promises`

### The Problem

Consider the code

```
getC3(): Observable<Country[]> {
  return this.http.get<Country[]>(this.link)
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => <Country[]>res.countries)
    .then(data => {return data});
  }
```

Thw line `return this.http.get<Country[]>(this.link)` will return an `Observable`. If you call `.toPromise()` on an `Observable` this returns a `Promise`. You will hence get the error that `Promise<Country[]> does not contain properties ... from type Observable<Country[]>`

### Solution

One way (the better way) to solve this to simply maintain the type as Observable.

```
getC3(): Observable<Country[]> { return this.http.get<Country[]>(this.link)}
```

I wouldn't recommend below, Changing the return type to promise

```
getC3(): Promise<Country[]> {
  return this.http.get<Country[]>(this.link)
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => <Country[]>res.countries)
    .then(data => {return data});
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, at least I can continue as I do