# How to access json file imported into Angular

Tags: node.js, json, angular

I am importing a json file via:

```
import * as menuJson from './menu.json';
```

If console.log menuJson I get:

[image]

If I try to console.log menuJson.default I get:

[image]

The error is:

```
Property 'default' does not exist on type
```

How can I turn turn this back into regular json and not a module so I can access the json content?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5 Service to read local .json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206924/angular-5-service-to-read-local-json-file)

Answer (score 0):

If your Typescript version is 2.9+, you can Do the followings:

Add these to your `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

and import your json:

```
import menu from './menu.json';
```

Comment: I did try this and unfortunately its still coming over as a module.