# Read JSON file from file in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a JSON file `config.json` saved in the `src/app/config` directory.

```
[
  "caseSensitive",
  "matchKeywords",
  "items"
]
```

I have to read the file and get the content of the JSON file without parsing it.

After searching for it, I got two ways

1. Add `"resolveJsonModule": true` to the `tsconfig.json` file
2. Declara a typing module `declare module "*.json" {}`

and importing JSON as

```js
import * as data from './app/config/config.json';


export class SchemaService {

  constructor() { }

  getConfig() {
    console.log('bool: ', data);                         // Output in screenshot
    console.log('type: ', typeof BooleanData);           // object
    console.log('parsed: ', JSON.stringify(BooleanData));
  }
}
```

But both the ways are giving the parsed output as

[image]

The `JSON.stringify(BooleanData)` statement is not giving the actual JSON file, instead, the array items are changed to key-value where the index is represented as key

```
{
  "0":"caseSensitive",
  "1":"matchKeywords",
  "2":"items"
}
```

**How can I read the raw JSON (without parsing) in Angular, or at least convert an object into JSON?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5 Service to read local .json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206924/angular-5-service-to-read-local-json-file)

Comment: @R.Richards this does not actually answer my question. Using `HttpClient` will stop working when there is no connection, also it requires putting the data file in the `assets` directory, whereas in my case, it is there in its module directory.

Comment: Looks like a jsonModule is expected to always be an object. You can try { data: [
  "caseSensitive",
  "matchKeywords",
  "items"
]} and then do the import as import { data } from './app/config/config.json';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a quickfix provide by @amer-yousuf But it will also let you import any `.js` file into your codebase as well. I wont prefer that. Here is an alternative approach

Define your `config.json.ts` (notice it ends with `.ts` and not `.json`) something like below

```
export const CONFIG = { // your JSON is assigned to CONFIG variable
    "say": "hello world"
}
```

In your other `.ts` file where you want to use, use something like following code

```
import { CONFIG } from './config.json';

// ...

console.log(CONFIG.say);

// ...
```

Benefit of this method:

1. You can still use tslint/eslint on config.json.ts
2. Most editors will auto-complete for you

Answer (score 2):

In Angular, to access the `JSON` as an object, you need to add the following two options to the `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
```

Then you can import it within your service like the following:

```js
import data from './app/config/config.json';
```

Answer (score 2):

To access JSON as Module in Angular you should add these two lines into tsconfig.json file

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

Then you can import it anywhere you want within the app

```
import  *  as  Characters  from  './configs/characters.json';
```

Finaly access the object from module

```
export class CharactersComponent {
    public characters: CharacterModel[] = (Characters as any).default;
}
```