# how can i fetch my local json file in angular 13.2 and display data with html

Tags: json, angular, typescript

its literally my third day trying to do that.thats what i achieved ,it displays nothing
,what i really want to do is to fetch data from lacal json so that **every json element will be displayed in a html block**

`Service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getJSON().subscribe(matches => console.log(matches))};
        public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get("./matches.json");
  }
  }
```

`component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-matches',
  templateUrl: './matches.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./matches.component.css']
})
export class MatchesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private ApiService : ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.ApiService.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

}
```

`matches.json`

```
[{"id":"1","homeTeam":"Es Tunis","awayTeam":"Tatawin","dateM":"2022-04-21","stade":"Rades","NBtickets":"20000"},
{"id":"2","homeTeam":"Rejiche","awayTeam":"Etoile du sahel","dateM":"2022-04-11","stade":"Mahdia","NBtickets":"15000"},
{"id":"3","homeTeam":"Cs Cheba","awayTeam":"Solimane","dateM":"2022-04-11","stade":"Cheba","NBtickets":"5000"},
{"id":"4","homeTeam":"Zarzis","awayTeam":"Club Africain","dateM":"2022-04-11","stade":"Jlidi","NBtickets":"10000"},
{"id":"5","homeTeam":"Olympique Beja","awayTeam":"Monastir","dateM":"2022-04-11","stade":"Boujemaa Kmiti","NBtickets":"15500"},
{"id":"6","homeTeam":"Ca Bizert","awayTeam":"Cs Sfaxien","dateM":"2022-04-11","stade":"Tayeb mhiri","NBtickets":"10000"},
{"id":"7","homeTeam":"Hammam-sousse","awayTeam":"Ben Gerdane","dateM":"2022-04-11","stade":"Bouaali hwar","NBtickets":"12000"},
{"id":"8","homeTeam":"hammam-Lif","awayTeam":"Metlaoui","dateM":"2022-04-11","stade":"Stade municipale","NBtickets":"10000"}]
```

why wont my code display anything?
ps:i tried many things such as importing file.json but nothing worked(im beginner)

Comment: You are writing your service file in totally wrong way. Wait let me fix it for you. Provide me your html template too.

Comment: first thanks ,but all the html related to this problem  now is a void component with <app-header></app-header> in app.component.html because i still dont know what kind of html i'll write

Comment: You are messing up with things. You don't need to create a service file just for rendering staic data. Along with service you need to have an model.ts file as well which I haven't seen anywhere. The matches.json is a static string. I will show you how to render your static data in html template. And rest for services and all you have to learn it properly.

Comment: Give me your html template.

Comment: what should i do bro

Comment: You should learn it from very basic. Just copying code is not going to work here. You can't have a solution until you learn it.

Comment: i really know that but i have a school project and the teacher gave us two weeks to end a whole angular project with php backend,i tried but i think its time for sleep

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qekk7b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). aren't you trying to make something like this?

Comment: yes according to the html but i cant do that with json data because i made it with php with backend informations

Comment: You are messing up with services. In service you should like something write this :  `constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getJson(){
    this.http.get() .subscribe()}`

Comment: You shouldn't write responses inside the `{}` after constructor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206924/angular-5-service-to-read-local-json-file

Comment: it was an answer to this question

Comment: That is something new I didn't know. Try to follow the codes from there. And search for errors here.