# How to get token expiration with `jsonwebtoken` using typescript

Tags: typescript, jwt, json-web-token

I'm using `jsonwebtoken` to decode a token, and I'm trying to get the expiration date. Typescript is throwing errors regarding the `exp` property, and I'm not quite sure how to solve them:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

const tokenBase64 = 'ey...' /* some valid token */

const token = jwt.decode(tokenBase64)
const tokenExpirationDate = token.exp
//                                ^^^
// Property 'exp' does not exist on type 'string | object'. Property 'exp' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

I have installed `@types/jsonwebtoken`, and looked for a token type to cast `token`, but did not find any. Suggestions?

Using

- `@types/jsonwebtoken@7.2.3`
- `jsonwebtoken@8.1.0`

.tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "jsx": "Preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ESNext"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

This is how I am using decode with TS

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export const isTokenExpired = (token: string): boolean => {
    try {
        const { exp } = jwt.decode(token) as {
            exp: number;
        };
        const expirationDatetimeInSeconds = exp * 1000;

        return Date.now() >= expirationDatetimeInSeconds;
    } catch {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Not needed but here you go as well

```
import 'jest';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

import { isTokenExpired } from 'path-to-isTokenExpired/isTokenExpired';

describe('isTokenExpired', () => {
    it('should return true if jwt token expired', () => {
        const currentTimeInSecondsMinusThirtySeconds = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) - 30;
        const expiredToken = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar', exp: currentTimeInSecondsMinusThirtySeconds }, 'shhhhh');

        expect(isTokenExpired(expiredToken)).toEqual(true);
    });

    it('should return false if jwt token not expired', () => {
        const currentTimeInSecondsPlusThirtySeconds = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 30;
        const notExpiredToken = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar', exp: currentTimeInSecondsPlusThirtySeconds }, 'shhhhh');

        expect(isTokenExpired(notExpiredToken)).toEqual(false);
    });

    it('should return true if jwt token invalid', () => {
        expect(isTokenExpired('invalidtoken')).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I got the same error message when I used the line `import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'`
With `var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');` [1] instead it works fine:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var tokenBase64 = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiZXhwIjoiMTUxMTk1MDcwMyIsImFkbWluIjp0cnVlfQ.wFC-9ZsqA9QuvLkRSkQmVYpUmgH9R-j8M4D0GECuPHY';

const token = jwt.decode(tokenBase64);
const tokenExpirationDate = token.exp
console.log(tokenExpirationDate);
```

[1] see also https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken

Comment: thanks for updating your question. The problem is caused by `import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'`. I updated my answer accordingly. Hope it will work for you. If you get an error that require can't be found do `npm install @types/node --save-dev`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require

Comment: This works, but it would be nice if anyone has a solution where one could still use import instead of require. Perhaps the typings file should be altered.

Answer (score 9):

The only way I found to user import is:

```
import { sign, verify } from 'jsonwebtoken';
sign('Hello', 'secret');
```

But I think the `require` method is better so that you don't have to explicitly import every single function.

Comment: How about this error after implementing your answer? `Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Secret'`' Any ideas?

Comment: @chris The only way I found to get rid of
 ```ts
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Secret
```
was to create my own type definitions. With regards to the secret key I had to do the following 
```ts
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface ProcessEnv {
    JWT_SECRET: string,
    JWT_EXPIRATION: string,
    TOKEN_ISSUER: string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As of jsonwebtoken 8.3, `jsonwebtoken.decode()` has the following type definitions:

```
export function decode(
    token: string,
    options?: DecodeOptions,
): null | { [key: string]: any } | string;
```

Since Typescript cannot infer the correct type and `exp` is not known, the simplest way out is to cast the result to `any`.

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

const tokenBase64 = 'ey...' /* some valid token */

const token: any = jwt.decode(tokenBase64)
const tokenExpirationDate = token.exp
```

Comment: I am having this issue: Module '"./node_modules/@types/jsonwebtoken/index"' has no default export.

Answer (score 4):

I think `import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';` should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

const { authorization } = ctx.req.headers
const token = authorization.replace('Bearer ', '')
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'APP_SECRET')
const userId = (decoded as any).userId
```

Of course you can type `decoded` the way you use the token instead of `any`

Comment: yeah this worked amongst all other options

Answer (score 2):

The return type of jwt.verify and jwt.decode is `'string | object'`.

In your case, you have some additional information that Typescript does not have about the type of the return type. So you can add it like this:

```
const token = jwt.decode(tokenBase64) as {exp: number}
const tokenExpirationDate = token.exp
```

Of course you can add any other value in the object as well.

While it's reasonable to assume that `exp` is present, other keys might not be present. Make sure that the token you are decoding actually includes them or add it as an optional value: (`{exp: number; random?: string}`)

Answer (score 0):

I found myself creating a helper for this (class based solution - can be used as separate function of course):

```
import { JwtPayload, verify } from "jsonwebtoken";

export class BaseController {
  // ...
  static decodeJWT = <T extends { [key: string]: any }>(token: string) => {
    return verify(token, process.env.JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN!) as JwtPayload & T; 
    // this typing allows us to keep both our encoded data and JWT original properties
  };
}
```

used in controllers like:

```
import { BaseController } from "./BaseController";

export class UserController extends BaseController {
  static getUser = async (
    // ...
  ) => {
    // get token
    // username may or may not be here - safer to check before use
    const payload = this.decodeJWT<{ username?: string }>(token); 
    // no error here, we can extract all properties defined by us and original JWT props
    const { username, exp } = payload;
    // do stuff...
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```ts
import jwt, { JwtPayload } from 'jsonwebtoken'

const tokenBase64 = 'ey...' /* some valid token */

const token = jwt.decode(tokenBase64) as JwtPayload
const tokenExpirationDate = token.exp
//                                ^^^
// token is now seen as a JwtPayload instance and you can use it's properties such as 'exp'.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).