# Typescript: Cannot find name require

Tags: typescript

I'm getting this error on vscode:

[image]

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "font-awesome-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test font-awesome with webpack",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:jeusdi/fontawesome-webpack.git",
  "author": "Jordi Cabré",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW the text of the error message doesn't show up in the screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typescript getting error TS2304: cannot find name ' require'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require)

Answer (score 5):

TypeScript can understand `require` after adding the Node type definitions:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

Shorthand:

```
npm i -D @types/node
```

Or with `yarn`:

```
yarn add -D @types/node
```

Also, you'll probably want to use

```
"moduleResolution": "Node",
```

in `tsconfig.json` to avoid different errors like

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'abc'
```

Answer (score 5):

I face the same error, when checked tsconfig.app.json file, it have:

```
"types": []
```

Just changed to

```
"types": ["node"]
```

And now everything is working smooth!

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript supports two different module resolution strategies: [Classic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#classic) and [Node](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#node). The default is Classic.

In order to use the `require('package')` method, you need to change your module resolution strategy to `Node` in the `compileOptions` of your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "moduleResolution": "node",
}
```

Comment: This addresses other errors like `TS2307: Cannot find module 'abc'` but it's not sufficient for the `require` error posted.