# After update webpack and Angular receives an error Cannot find name 'setImmediate'

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I've project created using `Visual Studio Angular Template`. I recently updated my `Angular` from 6 to 7 and `Typescript` to **3.1.6**. Also upgraded `Webpack` from 3.8.1 to **3.12.0**.

Now when I try to compile using webpack command I get the following error

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts:30:17
        TS2304: Cannot find name 'setImmediate'.
```

This error is thrown from boot.server.ts code

```
return platformDynamicServer(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(moduleRef => {
        const appRef: ApplicationRef = moduleRef.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
        const state = moduleRef.injector.get(PlatformState);
        const zone: NgZone = moduleRef.injector.get(NgZone);

        return new Promise<RenderResult>((resolve, reject) => {
            zone.onError.subscribe((errorInfo: any) => reject(errorInfo));
            appRef.isStable.pipe(first(isStable => isStable)).subscribe(() => {
                // Because 'onStable' fires before 'onError', we have to delay slightly before
                // completing the request in case there's an error to report
                setImmediate(() => {
                    resolve({
                        html: state.renderToString()
                    });
                    moduleRef.destroy();
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

I'm trying to fix this for some time but no success. Any idea>

Comment: I didn't find a solution to this. So in end I commented out the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem, but I think I figured out what the issue was. I had to install the typing declaration files for node.

In package.json add

```
"@types/node": "10.12.18",
```

Also make sure that your tsconfig.json is including the type files correctly. Either add 'node' to your "types" array if you are explicitly including the type files manually:

```
"types": ["node"]
```

or use the "typeRoots" property:

```
"typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ]
```

I prefer the second option, as then all the @type packages you install will automatically get recognized by your IDE.

---

This question is for a similar issue, the answer there goes into more detail than I did: [typescript getting error TS2304: cannot find name ' require'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require?rq=1)

Comment: One thing to note here this solution doesn't work with webpack v4

Answer (score 1):

You can use (window) before setImmediate

```
return new Promise<RenderResult>((resolve, reject) => {
        zone.onError.subscribe((errorInfo: any) => reject(errorInfo));
        appRef.isStable.first(isStable => isStable).subscribe(() => {
            // Because 'onStable' fires before 'onError', we have to delay slightly before
            // completing the request in case there's an error to report
            (<any>window).setImmediate(() => {
                resolve({
                    html: state.renderToString()
                });
                moduleRef.destroy();
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

sorry my bad. run "npm install" command from cmd or powershell. it should fix the issue.

Comment: it didn't fix it.

Comment: I am getting the same error message. I am doing the same thing with upgrading everything for my .net angular project. Upgrading to the latest version. If you find a solution please post here. I am stuck as well!