# "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require" in Excel JavaScript custom function

Tags: office-js, custom-functions-excel, scriptlab

I'm trying to run a custom function that requires two third-party libraries. I added the libraries to the libraries' pane like this:

```
@tensorflow/tfjs@1.5.1

@tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.4.0

sentence-tokenization@1.0.2
```

I get these errors:

```
{
    "error": [
        "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports",
        "https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.4.0/dist/index.js",
        32,
        30,
        {
            "message": "Can't find variable: exports",
            "line": 32,
            "column": 30,
            "sourceURL": "https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.4.0/dist/index.js",
            "stack": "global code@https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.4.0/dist/index.js:32:30"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "error": [
        "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require",
        "https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/",
        38,
        17,
        {
            "message": "Can't find variable: require",
            "line": 38,
            "column": 17,
            "sourceURL": "https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/",
            "stack": "global code@https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/:38:17"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "error": [
        "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require",
        "https://unpkg.com/sentence-tokenization@1.0.2/tokenizers.js",
        1,
        19,
        {
            "message": "Can't find variable: require",
            "line": 1,
            "column": 19,
            "sourceURL": "https://unpkg.com/sentence-tokenization@1.0.2/tokenizers.js",
            "stack": "global code@https://unpkg.com/sentence-tokenization@1.0.2/tokenizers.js:1:19"
        }
    ]
}
```

The code for the custom function also complains about require, but I was able to resolve it with this.

```
declare var require: any;
```

I found the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require) but not sure how to get this to work with the libraries.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to try this? `npm install --save-dev @types/node`. Use typescript v2

Comment: Excel runs JavaScript in a web browser context. Nodejs packages are not available