# 'require' and 'export' warnings in my index.ts file?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing Firebase cloud functions in a dart/flutter environment using TypeScript. (I think I'm using TS--I just renamed `index.js` to `index.ts` and change `package.json` line to `"main"; "index.ts"`)

I can deploy my functions fine and they work great but am getting the warnings below for `require` and `export`.

[image]

There's a relevant conversation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require) but couldn't find an option that worked, so resorted to the hacky `declare var require: any` which shut off the warnings but Firebase didn't like it?

[image]

Comment: If you want to use TypeScript with Cloud Functions using the Firebase CLI, you should consider just running `firebase init` all over again and letting the tool configure your project correctly for TypeScript.  It's not enough to just rename files from js to ts.

Comment: Thanks, Doug. Do I run that from within the `functions` folder?

Comment: [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#initialize_a_firebase_project) indicates that one should run the firebase init command from within the concerned app's directory.

Comment: Above comments saved the day. I deleted by old `functions` folder and ran `firebase init` from my project root and it created a new `functions` folder and all the necessary files