# Typescript imports destroys lookup?

Tags: node.js, typescript, import

I am trying to use a nodejs library like [uuid](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid) in my typescript app. This simple import works just fine if I want to only use it in a specific class:

```
import { v4 } from "uuid";

class MyClass {
...
}
```

However, this makes the class `MyClass` not "discoverable" by any other files in my solution. Sure I could `export` it, but that forces me to `import` the class in every usage, and the problem spreads like a cancer to every file. Do I really have to import/export every single class/file in my application just because I want to produce a simple UUID?

I saw that I can use `require` instead, however typescript doesn't know what that keyword is. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require) question but neither installing `@types/node` nor the quick and dirty `declare var require any` works.

It really seems like I am jumping through a lot of unnecessary hoops just to generate a uuid in typescript. Am I doing something very wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "discoverable"? Even if you didn't import the library, you would still have to export the class and import it where you want to use it, because every file is a module in js/ts.

Comment: I've been including them in my `index.html` with `<script>` tags manually.. Maybe that is the "very wrong" thing to do...

Comment: You should build your source files and include the resulted bundle file in `index.html`, for example: `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`. This will take care of the imports, but you still have to export/import, don't include them in a specific order and use the classes globally. Here are some link that can help you: [tooling](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-tooling-in-5-minutes.html), [migrating-from-js](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html), [compiler-options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).